# how to blur the background apart from ROI in android using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

Hi I would like to blur the whole background without blurring the vehicle/ROI as shown in the image below. Are there any android sample codes for this where I can refer to ? I had been searching around the internet but I don't seem to be able to find anything regarding this written in android java.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The most straightforward way is to clone the ROI, blur the entire image, and copy the ROI back to the blurred image.